# How to indent a data table with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to indent some data in a table.

The class I'm using currently is:

```
.table tbody tr.table-indent{
    padding-left:50px solid #bdbdbd;
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working with padding, margins, or a border. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Remove `solid #bdbdbd`?

Comment: you have to pad the <td> and not <tr>

Comment: Yeeeeah. I'm not convinced you need the properties for a border on your padding.

Comment: When using `.table`, you must remember to give your table the class `table`

Comment: @EsbenBoye-Jacobsen ONLY IFif you're using bootstrap..

Comment: I took both Xufox and Matteo Rubini's advice,  and it is now working.  Thanks so much to both of you!

Comment: @Siguza Yes. But if you read the comment I was replying to. It implied that the class of `table` MUST be added to a table. Which it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. Your code has some syntaxt errors. It should be something like that:

   ```
   .table tbody tr.table-indent{
       padding-left:50px;
   }
   ```

if you want a border on your row too:

```
    .table tbody tr.table-indent{
        padding-left:50px 
        border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
    }
```

2. You should really add padding on a table cell instead of a row:

   ```
   .table tbody tr.table-indent td:first-child{
       padding-left:50px        
   }
   ```

The :first-child selector will catch just the first cell of each row.